# Python Same Row Selection in Multiple List Boxes

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox, listboxitem

My problem is i can not select all same row datas in multiple listboxes in python-tkinter. Currently I have 5 different list boxes .I am using Python and tkinter.Also i am using one Excel workbook which has 5 different columns inside of it. How can i select all 5 listboxes datas which comes from same row number by selecting from just one list box. How can i do this? I tired index method but i couldnt understand it well.You can say every solutions that u have. So far i have tried listindex method but i couldnt be successful with it,i did not understand how to use it.

Comment: Can you please add minimal reproducible code and what you have tried so far? Then we can help you.

Comment: @BryanOakley I think OP wants to *synchronise* the selected row across the five listboxes, so it is not a duplicate of the linked question.

Comment: @acw1668: ok, I'll vote to reopen.

Comment: i have one 2 list box when i get one selection of one of these list boxes at the same time i want to select the item from other list box which is at the same row number . You can send a code from sracth no problem

Comment: SO is not the place to ask for code from scratch.  You need to try it yourself and post the code and the problem you come across.

Comment: for item in col_a:
    listbox_1.insert(END,item.value)

for item in col_d:
    listbox_2.insert(END,item.value)  Entry_1= Entry(window3,width=20)

Entry_1.place(x=700,y=300)

Entry_2= Entry(window3,width=20)   
def insert_selected():                                                                                                
 value_new = listbox_1.get(listbox_1.curselection())
 value_new2 = listbox_projects2.get(listbox_projects2.curselection())

Comment: Entry_1.insert(0, string=value_new)
    Entry_2.insert(0, string=value_new2)

col_a.listbox_projects1.Selected(col_d.listbox_projects2.ListIndex) = True

button_func=Button(window3, text="funct",command=insert_selected).pack()

Comment: these are codes of mine,  for example when i selected 4th row from first list box i want to select 4th row data from second list box at the same time cause then i will combine these data to create a senctences like string join function.Thanks a lot i need the solution so urgently.